# Azure Policy not enforced

Tags: azure, tags, policy

Trying to create a policy tied to a subscription in Azure that will deny the create of a resource group without a specific "costCenter" tag.  I have the following policy assigned to the subscription with the "coreTagName1" completed as "costCenter":

```
 "properties": {
   "displayName": "manual_test_1",
   "policyType": "Custom",
   "mode": "Indexed",
   "description": "manual test for tag enforcement",
   "metadata": {
     "category": "test",
     "createdBy": "#########",
     "createdOn": "2020-04-02T12:27:39.2686671Z",
     "updatedBy": "#########",
     "updatedOn": "2020-04-02T12:35:32.5608728Z"
   },
   "parameters": {
     "coreTagName1": {
       "type": "String",
       "metadata": {
         "displayName": "tagName to enforce",
         "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
       }
     }
   },
   "policyRule": {
     "if": {
       "anyOf": [
         {
           "field": "type",
           "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
         },
         {
           "exists": "false",
           "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('coreTagName1'), ']')]"
         }
       ]
     },
     "then": {
       "effect": "deny"
     }
   }
 },
 "id": "/subscriptions/#########/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/########",
 "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
 "name": "#######"
}
```

But i can still create a Resource Group and not specify any tags at all.  I feel like I am missing something fundamental in my approach but cant get my head round it yet.

Comment: It's likely that policy might be still in Compliance state of "Not started". Did you check the Compliance state?

Comment: ah that is indeed what was happening.  did not realise there was a lag between assigning the policy and it actually being enforced.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah! It takes sometime. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

as Jagrati mentioned. Please allow for sometime for the policy to run a compliance scan before checking for compliance results. (Typically wait time is 30 mins, but it depends heavily on scope and # of resources).